# MouseDown on TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I know many people asked same question, but after searching I couldn't find my answer yet.

Here is problem, I just want to touch TabItem of TabControl. 
So for this I can use MouseDown/MouseLeftButtonDown as I know.

I have adding  MouseDown/MouseLeftButtonDown for each TabItem,
Even I have adding MouseDown/MouseLeftButtonDown on TabControl(On this case, it's just work on area, not tabs)

Problem is tabItem isn't opens event after left clicking.

I have adding this, it's just works when user touch label of tabitem, so when user click on tabItem(Not label) this isn't works too

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">

<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>

            <Label Content="{Binding}">
                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                            <EventSetter Event="MouseDown"  Handler="TabItemMouseDown"/>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352791/wpf-label-click-event-not-getting-fired Try this. I don't think it has to do with Tab item " 
Why are you using a label if you obviously want a button or linkbutton behavio"

Comment: @Master please try to read question, because your answer isn't related to my question. anyway thanks

Comment: I think you need to look into Datatemplate and Header Templates. You are obviously putting a trigger on ONLY the label of the tab item. Why would you think it would trigger if you click elsewhere.

Comment: I have changing my code, not try to waste my time on this, It's too bad something like tabitem hasn't event of click or mouseDown(Mouse down isn't work but it has)